# JAVA: Scanner doesn't read next line // returns empty string

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

So I am programming Snake at the moment and i have a Method to read an an integer value from the console.
When my Method throws a mistake -  or atleast when i return to that method - 
it doesn't read in a new line from input but just passes a a empty string.
Here is my code:

```
static int readInInt()
{
    //We Read in the next line the user enters
    String s = sc.nextLine();
    //x returns -1 if mistake happens
    int x = -1;

    try
    {
        //Now we try to parse that int
        x = Integer.parseInt(s);
        x = Math.abs(x);
        System.out.println("Setting the speed to " + (x*100) + "ms.");
    }
    catch(NumberFormatException ex)
    {
        //If we can't parse it we try to get the ints with a regex and then parse it
        System.out.println("Du hast eine nummer eingetippt die das System nicht analysieren kann.");
        System.out.println("Das System probiert jetzt die Nummer die du eingetippt hast über umwege zu Analysieren.");
        s = s.replaceAll("[^-?0-9]+", "");   
        try
        {
            x = Integer.parseInt(s);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            //and if that doesnt work we just say Error!
            System.out.println("Error Handling didn't work.\n"
                    + "Please try again with just a simple number (e.g. 7)");            
            //Return an Error in form of -1
            return -1;
        }
        x = Math.abs(x);
        System.out.println("Setting the speed to " + (x*100) + "ms.");
    }

    return x;
}
```

I've declared "sc" as a static class variable `static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);` at the beginnning of my programm.

Why does the scanner return an empty String? - without asking for user input -
And yes i am aware of the Method .readNextInt, but i find it easyer to handle exceptions like this.

Comment: The code snippet you have shown seems to be ok. I assume a "problem" in another portion of your code. Most likely, you have read some other input with `sc.nextInt()` or similar. This method _does not consume_ a newline that is typed on the console. If you then go into your shown method, the statement `String s = sc.nextLine()` directly consumes this pending newline without waiting for any other input. You have to look at your other code, too.

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose
Thanks for the answer.
Bevor I access that method again, i ask the user if he wants a new game.
(y/n answer).
And if he wants a new game the returnInt() method gets accesed again.
 But that shouldn't be tha problem eversicne i acces sc.nextLine() throuout my programm (changing direction ect.) so i don't understand why it does that in that particular situation

Comment: I said, if in _another_ place `sc.nextInt()` was used, you have a pending newline that was not consumed. The next `sc.nextLine()` only consumes this newline and does not give the priority to enter anything. The problem, therefore, is in another portion of your code!

Comment: Just a sidenote - nothing to do with the problem: You are aware that you are mixing German and English output, right? ;)

Comment: where do you call readinInt

Comment: @Fildor yeap fully aware XD
I noticed it (i usually write comments in english and output in german) and then i was like '...Naaah to  lazy to edit' :D

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose thanks for the hint!
found the problem and posted the answer! I  hope it was okay for you that i've added you in the Answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @Seelenvirtuose who brought me to the right track of the solution!

> I said, if in another place sc.nextInt() was used, you have a pending newline that was not consumed. The next sc.nextLine() only consumes this newline and does not give the priority to enter anything. The problem, therefore, is in another portion of your code! –

The solution was that in some parts of my code i was using `sc.next()` which only reads in the next string untill the whitespace (if i am not mistaken) and not `sc.nextLine()`.
So I've changed all `sc.next()` to `sc.nextLine()` not it works just fine.

There are 2 other solutions that I've found while doing trail and error:
a) Write `sc.reset()` which does "*Resetting a scanner discards all of its explicit state information[...]*" bevor accesing the `sc.nextLine()`command or
b) Just create a new instance of the *Scanner* class.

Thanks again to [Seelenvirtuose](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2563754/seelenvirtuose).

Answer (score 0):

I solved using two different scanner: one for reading of int and float values and another for reading String.

```
Scanner scanString = new Scanner(System.in);
Scanner scanIntFloat = new Scanner(System.in);

int cod = scanIntFloat.nextInt();
String name = scanString.nextLine();
```

Elias.

Answer (score 0):

You can use two different **Scanners** .......

First Scanner for reading **int**,**float** and **double**.

Second Scanner for reading **String** values.

Like Below......

```
Scanner scanIntFloat = new Scanner(System.in);
Scanner scanString = new Scanner(System.in);

int cod = scanIntFloat.nextInt();
String name = scanString.nextLine();
```

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar issue.
What i did was add a nextLine(); command after the next(); command to catch the character filling up the buffer that is inserted where you put your input request.

Basically:

- word = scan.next();
  --Input whatever word you need
- catcher = scan.nextLine();
  --Catches the character that fills up the buffer
- input2 = scan.nextLine();
  --Input your following line

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

That's a Scanner bug. After reading non-String values, call `nextLine()` on the Scanner object, then read the actual line you intend reading using `nextLine()`